# How prove $a*b=b*a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let $x,y$ be  any real numbers,define $*$,such
$$x=(x*y)*y=y*(y*x)$$
fo any $a,b$,show that
$$a*b=b*a$$

My try:
$$x=(x*y)*y=y*(y*x)$$
then
$$y=(y*x)*x=x*(x*y)$$
so
$$y*x=x*(x*y)*x$$
and
$$x*y=y*(y*x)*y$$
then I can't,Thank you

Comment: Is your operation associative?

Comment: With only above definition of * you can not prove commutativity, there is alot of counter example.

Comment: My point is that you should not write $a\ast b\ast c$ without parentheses.

Comment: @FarshadNahangi,why?

Comment: forgive me @ china math I had mistake

Comment: Here's the proof: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Ordinal_Multiplication_is_Associative

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start from the result and do the only things you can (multiply by things that make something go away):

$\begin{align}
a\ast b&=b\ast a\\
(a\ast b)\ast a &= b\\
(a\ast b)\ast((a\ast b)\ast a) &= (a\ast b) \ast b\\
a&=a
\end{align}$

Now, read upwards to get a proof (you have to left-multiply by $a\ast b$ to get from line 3 to line 2, and right-multiply by $a$ to get from line 2 to line 1).

Comment: Note that it is really impossible not to find the solution with this approach: at the first step, all four possible multiplications are equally useful, at the second step, one of the possibilities takes you back to the beginning and the other one finishes the task.

Comment: This proof cannot be accepted. How do you go back from line 3 to line 2, or from line 2 to line 1 without the cancelation rule? Unless you first prove the cancelation rule.